# Really struggling on coming up with a clever business name

Tags: phrase-requests

Long story short, I’ve been toying with the idea of restoring an old vintage camper and turning it into a photo booth mostly for weddings (though other events would be fine too). There’s a need in my area and I have the experience/tools to do so.

Logistics aside, I really want to come up with a clever name. Something related to camping/maybe weddings/photography/wilderness/etc somehow.

The few options I have currently, but aren't in love with, are:

- Snappy Camper (it exists multiple times and is lacking wilderness terms)
- Northern Routes (I'm in the North East and liked that "Routes" could also be "Roots," not sure which is better, but it's lacking photography reference)
- Hitch the Road (no photography reference)

Some interesting keywords I can't seem to make into a camping or photography related phrase:

- Wild
- Woods
- Captured
- Still
- NewlyWoods

I just want it to be a camping, wilderness, or photography term, but then relate to the other somehow. I know it's a lot to ask.

My husband and I have a homestead called “Wildernest” - a play on “wilderness” - which I am obsessed with. Hoping to feel the same about this name!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [naming requests are off-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: **Camp**turing moments (capturing moments?)

Comment: **Great wild-shots** (ack, the question is off-topic but I really like it. Good luck on your fledging business)

Comment: A Postcard Home  .. might have some play ... especially if your speciality photo's had props and fake backdrops etc

Answer (score 0):

I would list all of the synonyms you can find for *camping* and all of the synonyms you can find for *photography* and see where they might intersect.

(I like *wildernest*—that's a great play on words.)

I immediately thought of *wildstock*—but it's not an obvious play between "wild" and "stock photography" because it already spells a common word. (Not unless you made it something like ***Wild Stock Adventures***. I'm actually partial to that, but but I'm not sure how many people would get the reference.)

I may revisit this answer if I can think of something.